# react useEffect cleanup function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

```
    export default function Quiz() {
  const [userAnswers, setUserAnswers] = useState([]);

  const activeQuestionIndex = userAnswers.length;
  const quizIsComplete = activeQuestionIndex === QUESTIONS.length;

  function handleSelectAnswer(selectedAnswer) {
    setUserAnswers((prevUserAnswers) => {
      return [...prevUserAnswers, selectedAnswer];
    });
  }

  const handleSkipAnswer = useCallback(() => handleSelectAnswer(null), [handleSelectAnswer]);

  if (quizIsComplete) {
    return (
      <div id="summary">
        <img src={quizCompleteImg} alt="Trophy icon" />
        <h2>Quiz Completed!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const shuffledAnswers = [...QUESTIONS[activeQuestionIndex].answers];
  shuffledAnswers.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

  return (
    <div id="quiz">
      <div id="question">
        <QuestionTimer
          key={activeQuestionIndex}
          timeout={10000}
          onTimeout={() =>  handleSelectAnswer(null)}
        />
        <h2>{QUESTIONS[activeQuestionIndex].text}</h2>
        <ul id="answers">
          {shuffledAnswers.map((answer) => (
            <li key={answer} className="answer">
              <button onClick={() => handleSelectAnswer(answer)}>
                {answer}
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is my Quiz component, and in the return block, i have a

```
    <QuestionTimer
          key={activeQuestionIndex}
          timeout={10000}
          onTimeout={() =>  handleSelectAnswer(null)}
        />
```

the key here is used to update the QuestionTimer component when the state userAnswers changes, What i think is the new-coming QuestionTimer component will generated when the userAnswers change, and the old QuestionTimer is gone. Next is the detail of QuestionTimer.

```
    export default function QuestionTimer({ timeout, onTimeout }) {
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(timeout);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('SETTING TIMEOUT');
    const timer = setTimeout(onTimeout, timeout);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log('SETTING INTERVAL');
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setRemainingTime((prevRemainingTime) => prevRemainingTime - 100);
    }, 100);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return <progress id="question-time" max={timeout} value={remainingTime} />;
}
```

the problem is why i need the `clearTimeout(timer);` and `clearInterval(interval);`,
In my view, whether to clean up or not doesn't make a difference, as a new QuestionTimer is generated.
i have tried the scenario without two line code，but i cannot run the application properly.

Comment: *"why i need the clearTimeout(timer); and clearInterval(interval);"* - Those are used to clear the timeout and the interval.  Without them, a new timeout and new interval is created any time the component is initially loaded.  In your specific scenario that may not be a problem, in other scenarios it may be a problem.  The standard practice is to clean up resources create by an effect, because there's really no compelling reason **not** to.  In your specific case, is something not working as expected?

Comment: At first, I did include cleanup code. However, when I added the key to the QuestionTimer component called in the App component, I thought the old QuestionTimer would be replaced, so I deemed cleanup unnecessary and removed the code

Comment: That's all well and good, but in the code shown in the question is something not working as expected?  What specifically are you asking?

Comment: If you want to restart your timers on `key` change, you should include `key` in the effects' dependency arrays. That's when the cleanup functions will become important too.

Comment: When the key changes, does the QuestionTimer component returned in the Quiz component get re-rendered, or does it create a new QuestionTimer component?

Comment: It gets re-rendered, unless it's unmounted while the next question loads or something, which I assume it doesn't. Either way, not including the cleanup, especially for timers can have unintended side effects. just do it.

Comment: @姚海涵: You could test this by including some visible output in the `useEffect` and its cleanup function.  What happens when you try?

Comment: @David You shouldn't rely on console.log debugging here. React reserves the right to unmount components and re-mount them later under certain circumstances, even with an empty deps array. To get devs used to writing cleanup functions, they've been double-calling effects in Strict-Mode since v18

Comment: thank you david and dustin  i dont know how to @ you guys, the QuestionTimer is re-rendered, and the old timeout and old interval still there. i need clean them up.